# How to get base_url() while running via CLI Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, cron

I am trying to send email using crontab, In the email body there are some images that need to give base_url, Currently we are setting base_url dynamically.

Comment: I have done already ;), first understand the question then reply with solution if you know :)

Comment: I've CLI's working well and would like to help, but what do you mean with: "In the email body there are some images that need to give base_url, currently we are setting base_url dynamically". And further: how is your hosting setup (own server, Cpanel, etc.?)